# IF NOT EXIST Recored Select Some Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I wrote a query that selects highest record from tbl. I want check if there is no record in tbl my query return fake data like (StudentId = 1,HighScore=0)

```
var queryWin = (from T in ((from tbl_ActPoints in dc.tbl_ActPoints
                select new
                {
                    tbl_ActPoints.StudentId,
                    tbl_ActPoints.Score
                }))
    group T by new
    {
        T.StudentId
    } into g
    orderby
      ((System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? (System.Int32?)0) descending
    select new
    {
        g.Key.StudentId,
        HighScore = ((System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? (System.Int32?)0)
    }).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var queryWin = (from T in ((from tbl_ActPoints in dc.tbl_ActPoints
                select new
                {
                    tbl_ActPoints.StudentId,
                    tbl_ActPoints.Score
                }))
    group T by new
    {
        T.StudentId
    } into g
    orderby
      ((System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? (System.Int32?)0) descending
    select new
    {
        g.Key.StudentId,
        HighScore = ((System.Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? (System.Int32?)0)
    }).Take(1);

var result = queryWin.FirstOrDefault();

if (result == null)
  result = new { StudentId = 1, HighScore=0 };
```

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up your code a bit:

```
var queryWin = (from tbl_ActPoints in dc.tbl_ActPoints
                group new
                {
                    tbl_ActPoints.StudentId,
                    tbl_ActPoints.Score
                } by tbl_ActPoints.StudentId into g
                orderby
                  (g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? 0) descending
                select new StudentHighScore
                {
                    g.Key.StudentId,
                    HighScore = (g.Sum(p => p.Score) ?? 0)
                }).FirstOrDefault() 
                     ?? new StudentHighScore { StudentID = 1, HighScore = 0};
```

The trick, and the reason coolswastik's code didn't work, as that two anonymous objects, even with the same properties, are always different, so you need a named class:

```
class StudentHighScore
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int HighScore { get; set; }
}
```